# Delete everything after 3 character

Tags: sql-server, substring

Anybody knows how to delete everything after third '#' ?

I tried it like this but it's not working:

```
declare @s varchar(200) = 'abcd#efg#hij#delete';
select left(@S, charindex('@', @S, charindex('@', CHARINDEX('@',@S)+1)+1)-1);
```

Results should be 'abcd#efg#hij without '#delete'
Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you looking for an '@' sign, when you should be looking for the '#'? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for these is to always include the charindex functions as part of your SELECT statement so you can see them as you go along.

Using this method you'll be able to see your results as you go.

```
declare @s varchar(200) = 'abcd#efg#hij#delete';

SELECT CHARINDEX('#',@s) AS [FirstIndex]
,CHARINDEX('#',@s,CHARINDEX('#',@s)+1) AS [SecondIndex]
,CHARINDEX('#',@s,CHARINDEX('#',@s,CHARINDEX('#',@s)+1)+1) AS [ThirdIndex]
,LEFT(@s,CHARINDEX('#',@s,CHARINDEX('#',@s,CHARINDEX('#',@s)+1)+1)-1) AS [Final];
```

Returns: 'abcd#efg#hij'